# Email Settings API - How to delete Send-as alias

Tags: google-apps, google-admin-sdk

The Google Apps Email Settings API describes creating and retrieving Send-as aliases, but not how to delete them. Is it possible to do this via the API, or is there a workaround?

I'm using the Directory API to add and delete user aliases, which takes care of whether someone can receive at an alias, but I'm stuck on how to remove their Send-as alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sendas delete method. Users must manually delete the sendas from the UI.

Comment: Got confirmation from Google support that this is indeed the case. A feature request to add the delete method to the API has been made.

Comment: Here's the original feature request, dating from June 2011: [apps-api-issues](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2628)

Answer (score 2):

The ability to delete send-as aliases has been added to the API, though I haven't tested it myself  - https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/delete

Answer (score 0):

The [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/#Users.aliases) has a method to "delete all aliases". Not sure if that includes "sendas" alias but might be worth checking.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not affect sendas aliases.